# Get a disparity map from feature extraction of two images

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst, disparity-mapping

i have some understanding problems on how to get the disparity map from two images of one scene. 
I currently can extract some feature points and filter them so just the right correspondences are shown (lets say there are in total 60 feature points i can get).

To get the disparity of x1 and x2, i know that i have to do this:

```
d = x1 - x2;
```

My problem is how to proceed from here. Both pictures have like 1000x1500 pixels and i only get the disparity of 60 pixels (because i have i.e. 60 feature points). 
How do i get the other disparities?

My current code (in matlab, self written) cant extract more than a cretain amount of features.

Should i look for a better extraction alogroithm?
Or is there another way to get the disparity from my current data? 
(i can also calculate the rotation matrix R, the translation matrix T, the essential matrix E, i have the baseline, the calibration matrix of both cameras and so on.)

I use the middleburry stereo data set from 2014. 
http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/

Thx in advance for any help:) (sorry if there are spelling errors)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you add your code to the question. [Keep this in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code i use is to large and i dont want to get some solution code. I just want to understand what i have to do from here on. Do i really need to extract the correspodning point for every pixel in the image, or is there a way (just explain pls!) on how to get the disparity from the few features points i get?

Comment: I have a theory: I extract the few feature points of my 2 images and search there correspondenes. Then i use this to reticify both images so that the same feature points of image1 and image2 are on the same horizontal line. From here on i can use some algorithm that can find a matching point for every pixel in image1. Then i calculate the disparities. Can this procedure work ?

Comment: Maybe https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/disparitybm.html helps.

Answer (score 1):

Disparity maps are generally linked to *dense* stereo vision.

Oppositely, resorting to feature extraction, you are in *sparse* domain.

Dense stereo matching algorithms will help you to obtain a disparity map. See https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/vision/ref/disparitybm.html for a matlab instance, or https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html for an OpenCV implementation.

The general idea is that with a dense method you try to match pixels (or more commonly blocks) between the left and right images.

Some more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577286/1687499) answer and in the documentation linked above.